# Append new elements to XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have base XML, to which I would like to add new elements. But it fails and I cannon understand why.

My base XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vehicleDefinitions>
    <vehicleType id="bus">
        <capacity>
            <seats persons="3"/>
            <standingRoom persons="9"/>
        </capacity>
        <length meter="12.3"/>
        <width meter="2.5"/>
        <accessTime secondsPerPerson="0.5"/>
        <egressTime secondsPerPerson="0.5"/>
        <doorOperation mode="serial"/>
        <passengerCarEquivalents pce="0.28"/>
    </vehicleType>
</vehicleDefinitions>
```

My code:

```
from lxml import etree

schedule = etree.parse('schedule_mapped.xml') #I use this file to get data from it
vehicles = etree.parse('vehicles.xml') #I'm reading my base XML
vehicles_root = vehicles.getroot() #Getting its root
for transitLine in schedule.findall('transitLine'):
    tstype = transitLine.find('transitRoute').find('transportMode').text
    for transitRoute in transitLine.findall('transitRoute'):
        for departure in transitRoute.find('departures').findall('departure'):
            tsname = departure.get('vehicleRefId')
            vehicle = etree.SubElement(vehicles_root, 'vehicle') #I want to add a child to my root element
            vehicle.attrib['id'] = tsname
            vehicle.attrib['type'] = tstype
```

The structure of my output XML is correct. I mean that children are added:

[image: current structure]

But after writing XML to file

```
with open(ts.replace('schedule', 'vehicles'), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(etree.tostring(vehicles,pretty_print=True,encoding='utf8'))
```

I got this
[image]

I discovered that the problem might be in [unreadable characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcPKc.png) from the base XML but I do not know how to cope this.

Comment: Did you just try `etree.write(output_filename)` and make sure to insert `\n` character for each tag you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found a solution. We can just parse XML without blank characters. It allows "pretty print" to work correctly.

```
def getClean(filename):
        parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
        cleanTree = etree.parse(filename, parser)
        return cleanTree
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, which can retrieve nodes from a different XML file using `document()` function. Additionally, you have better control of output including indentation and line breaks, headers, etc. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Doing so you avoid any application layer nested looping.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, to be used in Python below)*

Notice reference to other .xml file. Both XML files are assumed to be in same directory.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="vehicleDefinitions">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="vehicleType"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('schedule_mapped.xml')/descendant::departure">
          <vehicle id="{@vehicleRefId}" 
                   type="{../preceding-sibling::transportMode}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('vehicle.xml')
xsl = etree.parse('script.xsl')

transformer = etree.XSLT(xsl)
result = transformer(doc)

with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```